# Ссылки в PHP

Tags: php, ссылки

В каких ситуациях можно использовать ссылки в PHP? Например, что будет быстрее:

```
$get = &$_GET;
echo $get['id']; // это?

$get = $_GET;
echo $get['id']; // или это?
```

Пож-та объясните в каких случаях выгодно использовать ссылки, а то про существование знаю, а ни разу не пользовался)

Comment: Непонятный вопрос... Ссылки или GET запросы?

Comment: Это только пример для $_GET показан, может быть либой другой массив.

Comment: Вообще смысла не увидел в этом...

    echo $_GET['id'];

Comment: Солидарен)

Comment: Ну вы даёте, при чём тут смысл, а? мне интересно зачем используются теги, ни раз видел когда ставили ссылку на глобальные массивы, не по теме пишете тут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот вам кучка примеров) Основные применения ссылок - облегчение кода и экономия памяти, т.к. обращение по ссылке не копирует объект.

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach ($arr as &$v)
  $v = 5;
var_dump($arr);

$array = array(array(2, 3, array(15, 16)), array(1, 2, 3))
function &array_get(&$arr) {
  $tmp = &$arr;
  for ($i = 1; $i < func_num_args(); $i++) {
    $code = func_get_arg($i);
    if (!isset($tmp[$code])) return false;
    $tmp = &$tmp[$code];
    }
  return $tmp;
  }
$var = &array_get($array, 0, 2, 0);
echo $var; // 16
$var = 22; //  изменит значение в массиве

function my_recursive_procedure(&$array) {
  foreach ($array as &$v)
    if (is_array($v)) {
      my_recursive_procedure($v);
      } else $v = str_replace('a', 'b', $v);
  } // без ссылок было бы более громоздко + скопировался бы весь массив
my_recursive_procedure($array);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: foreach ($arr as &$v)
        $v = 5;

При использовании цикла с жесткой ссылкой *всегда* делайте unset в конце цикла, если не хотите получить очень трудноуловимый логический баг. Т.е. правильно так:

    foreach ($arr as &$v) {
        $v = 5;
        unset($v);
    }

Answer (score 4):

Перед тем как сделать выводы

*Да ссылки же очень удобные, еще и память экономят*

Настоятельно рекомендую, вдумчиво и внимательно почитать вот ***[это](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/43489/)***

[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) - почему ты не упомянул о том что такой код намного хуже читается и, при использовании ссылок, мы теряем порядка 30% производительности( в особых случаях даже больше ).

Лично я, в php, избегаю ссылок везде где это возможно и вам советую...

Comment: Найдете среди моих вариантов использование 2 ссылок на 1 объект?) Хабр хабром, а и там извращенцы есть и код, описанный в статье - нелогичен. Если нужно 2 объекта - надо делать 2 объекта. 

К слову,

    $a = array(1, 2, 3);
    $b = &$a; // обращаем внимание, в статье по-другому
    foreach ($a as &$val)
      $val = 5;
    var_dump($b); // 5, 5, 5 =) копирования так и не было

А кривые руки - это к дохтору уже.

Надо избегать не ссылки, а глупый код :)

**Суть: не надо использовать ссылки там, где они не нужны.** Так же как и любой другой элемент языка.

Comment: Спасибо, учту)

Comment: Cуть в том что любой код можно написать без их использования, посему они не нужны (во всяком случае я их не использую практически никогда)

Comment: Я крайне советую прочитать [статью Дерика Ретанса (PDF)](http://derickrethans.nl/files/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf), разработчика расширения xdebug, в которой детально расписывается механизм работы переменных PHP и то почему переменные по жесткой ссылке могут сильно увеличить расход памяти.

>     foreach ($arr as &$v)
>         $v = 5;

При использовании цикла с жесткой ссылкой *всегда* делайте unset в конце цикла, если не хотите получить очень трудноуловимый логический баг.

    foreach ($arr as &$v) {
        $v = 5;
        unset($v);
    }

Answer (score 3):

[Ссылки. Разъяснения](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/language.references.php)

Так же советую всем, кто еще не читал, прочитать статью Дерика Ретанса [References in PHP](http://derickrethans.nl/files/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Ссылки нужны, чтобы передавать переменные в функции и внутри функции работать с переменной как глобальной, но без объявления global $var;

Comment: а, понятно, спасибо, разве только для этого?))